# Executing return statement after try block without finally block

Tags: java, android

I have a code in Android in a method:

```
try {  
    something();  
    return obj;  
}
catch (Exception e) {   
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return null;
```

When I run the app in debugging mode both return statements get executed, even there is no finally block and compiler does need second return(when I clean it compiler says "missing return statement") how this can be possible? Is this always the case for try blocks even without finally?

Comment: "both return statements get executed" -- please edit your question and provide your evidence for this claim. "how this can be possible" -- it is not possible, which is why you need to explain why you think it is happening.

Comment: I think it's just shown by debugger that it's out of your try-catch block

Comment: @CommonsWare I think OP is stepping through the code and seeing how it jumps between each return statement, confusing him/her into thinking each statement is executed...

Comment: Yes I think it is only showed in debugging mode and it does not get executed, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. It's just shown by debugger that it's out of your try-catch block. Highlighted line does not means it's executed.

Answer (score 2):

You need second return (`return null;`) because if "something()" throws exception, then the first return (`return obj;`) will not be executed

Answer (score 0):

Impossible, Share your full code. Every function executes only one return statement i.e. when the "return" statement in your function is encountered, The execution of the function is halted and a value whether user defined or primitive is returned or you can say outputted to the user.